# Is $k$-largest order statistic $X_{(1)},\dots, X_{(k)}$ for $1\le k<n$ independent or identical distributed?

Tags: probability, statistics

If we have $n$ i.i.d. data $X_1,\dots, X_n$, we order its as $X_{(1)}\ge X_{(2)}\ge \dots X_{(n)}$.

**Question:** Is $k$-largest order statistic $X_{(1)},\dots, X_{(k)}$ for $1\le k<n$ independent or identical distributed?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: It's sure that they are not identical distributed. Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Cumulative_distribution_function_of_order_statistics  gives the density function of $X_{(i)}$ which are all different. And about the dependency, these variables are dependent to each other. Not a formal proof but they all depend on $X_1,...,X_n$

Comment: @NN2 If $x_1, x_2$ are two independent normally distributed random variable, then $\theta = \arctan(\frac{x_2}{x_1})$ and $r = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ (the angle and length of the vector $(x_1,x_2)$) are also independent. Sometimes you can mix independent variables and obtain independent variables. If you start with a correlation bivariate normal distribution and rotate it right, you will obtain two independent normals: sometimes you can mix dependent variables and obtain independent variables. In general, there is little to say about different functions of the same variables.

Comment: You could be asking one of several questions, most likely the answer will be no. One possible question is "Is there a distribution $F$ such that every $X_{(k)} \sim F$?" and the answer to that is "No", each $X_{(k)}$ has its own distribution. You could be asking "Are $(X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(i)})$ and $(X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(j)})$ identically distributed?" The answer is "Obviously not unless $i = j.$" You could be asking "Let $Y_k$ be the largest amongst $X_1, \ldots, X_k.$ Are the $Y_k$s identically distributed?" The answer is "Obviously not."